# Is it possible to insert a column in a database table automatically using a variable in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert a column in a database table automatically using a variable.

I have a table named `tbl_category`, I want to let the user choose the sub category field by their own choice. So, from the dashboard, the user will insert 3/4 (or how many fields they would like to create) sub category fields.

I will take this value as `$insert_sub_cat_count`. So, when this info will hit the function named `function save_category_info($data)`, the function will receive the value `$insert_sub_cat_count` as `$data`.

After that, this info have to implement in the table `tbl_category` and add 3/4 fields automatically according to the value `$data`.

If the user inputs `2`, this will insert two columns automatically:

[image]

If the user inputs `3`, this will insert 3 columns:

[image]

Is this possible? I don't know how to extend columns automatically or if there's any other way to do so.

Comment: they aren't rows, they are columns of your tables. And, use to create columns **is not at all good design**

Comment: so you want to create different table columns for each user? or you want to add rows to an existing column? it's totally different

Comment: My bad, question edited. It would be column, not row. Can anyone please help? :)

Comment: Very bad idea.. the same column names with increment are a SQL anti pattern.. you should check table normalization instead

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Thanks :) @JayBlanchard

Answer (score 1):

Insert is used to insert variables into an already existing column, you need to first create your column before filling it:

```
ALTER TABLE `tbl_category` ADD `sub_category_one` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad idea from the very start. As Raymond Nijland said above ("the same column names with increment are a SQL anti pattern.. you should check table normalization instead"), you shouldn't allow users to create columns with their desired name in your database. You should have the following tables:

```
user - id, name
categories - id, id_user, name
subcategories - id, id_category, id_user, name
```

So you will be able to link the category and subcategory to the user that created it. You don't need to create a separate column for each user.
If you're worried about speed you should add index for the subcategories table, for the column: id_user. In this way the search will work fast enough.

Comment: If you read carefully, evidently they are not letting the users name the column (which is why Raymond thinks they are auto incremented).

Comment: The approach the OP is taking here is normal with a pre-defined set of children allowed, but he want's to dynamically allow the user to define how many children a category can have, in theory, unlimited, for such approach, then this method is way better.